# How to select pair of userID that have at least 3 reviewed productID with a product score of at least 4/5 in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have a dataset like this:

| userid | productid | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 |
| A | 2 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 5 |
| B | 1 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 5 |

I want to have an output like this:

| userid1 | userid2 | matching_product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 2 3 |

but I'm only able to get the first two column with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE score_greater_than_3 AS
SELECT userid, productid, score
FROM reviews
WHERE score >= 4;

SELECT s1.userid as userid1, s2.userid as userid2
FROM score_greater_than_3 s1 
INNER JOIN score_greater_than_3 s2 ON s1.productid=s2.productid AND s1.userid<s2.userid
GROUP BY s1.userid, s2.userid
HAVING count(*)>=3;
```

How can i get the matching products? i'm ok with an output like this too if its more easy

| user1 | user2 | matched product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 1 |
| a | b | 2 |
| a | b | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT r.userid,
           r.productid
    FROM reviews r
    WHERE r.score > 3
)
SELECT r1.userid,
       r2.userid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(r1.productid SEPARATOR ' ')       
FROM       cte r1
INNER JOIN cte r2
        ON r1.productid = r2.productid
       AND r1.userid < r2.userid
GROUP BY r1.userid,
         r2.userid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

It uses a [Common Table Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) that allows you to allocate your table in a temporary space that lasts till the end of the query. Your next step using the self join is correct, though it lacks the [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregation function, that allows you to aggregate on a string-like field. You can set the "separator" parameter to decide which string you want to use to concatenate your values.

Try the full query [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bzs7EvWq5UduXgikVCA54U/0).

Comment: thank you! works  very good! also thank you for formatting my post :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
select s1.userid as userid1, s2.userid as userid2, 
GROUP_CONCAT(s1.productid) 
from score_greater_than_3 s1 inner join score_greater_than_3 s2 on s1.productid=s2.productid and s1.userid<s2.userid
group by s1.userid, s2.userid;
```

The whole script please see:  [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jC8PGeZZEuty3XVq8gdzz/5)

Comment: this is perfect but it select pairs that has less than 3  reviewed product in common too